# Integrating Jasper Reports and Solr

Tags: solr, jasper-reports

This very general question and answer suggests a custom datasource can be developed to integrate Jasper Reports and Solr:
  https://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/705431/it-possible-use-solr

Is anyone aware of any implementation out there already?

Anyone tried that?